# ag-grid comparator function not being triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid 9.X with angularJs and when trying to set the comparator function for a date column, it doesn't get triggered.

```
      {
      headerName: 'Date',
      field: 'lastDate',
      width:100,
      sortable: true,
      comparator: dateComparator,
      }
```

I also set `enableSorting: true` . Is there any chance that the feature is not available in that version of ag-grid ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried this.dateComparator?

Comment: did you click the sort Icon? it's triggered when you click the sort icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since I was not able to get the comparator function to work, I used the following tips to sort date columns :

- Making sure that the original data that feeds into the grid has Javascript Date objects for that column and not strings (so that ag-grid's sort algorithm (which uses the ">" operator) can compare these dates as dates and not strings) 
  Example :

  ```
          data.forEach(function(obj,i){
           let dateStr = obj.date
           let year = dateStr.substring(0, 4)
           let month =  dateStr.substring(5, 7)
           let day = dateStr.substring(8, 10)
           let time =  dateStr.substring(11, 21)
           let date = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+time)
           data[i].date = date
          })
          $scope.gridConfig.data = data
  ```

In fact, what I've come to realize through this issue is that ag-grid sorting algorithm doesn't act on the data rendered by cellRenderer nor the valueGetter. It actually uses the original data.

- Optional : These columns will be rendered in a Javascript date object **format**. 
  If you'd like to have a specific format for these dates, you can use the cellRenderer function or a valueGetter for that column to parse these dates back into the original format. And no worries, sorting won't be impacted as it will still use the date objects from the original data.

Comment: "It actually uses the original data." 
Thanks for this, you've spared me a lot of headaches.

Comment: This is not the actual answer for the question , this does not answer the question how did it get tick mark

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the following:

```
sort: 'asc',
```

Answer (score -2):

I think implementation of your comparator is the problem. are you using a static function? if not try this and see if it works.

```
{
    headerName: 'Date',
    field: 'lastDate',
    width:100,
    sortable: true,
    comparator: (a, b) => {
        //implement your comparator here.
    },
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answer differs from the code in the question. I would assume that the OP knows the proper signature of a comparator function; and the question states that the comparator isn't triggered at all.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.